# Vim regex, how to stop a matching expression with a / several specific characters?

Tags: vim

I want to match words starting with `e_` with a specific keyword in order to highlight them.

Here is what I have:

```
syntax match Enums "\<e_\S\+"
```

However the highlighting will continue until a whitespace, meaning it will color `;`, `)`, and so on.

How do I limit the expression to letters and `_` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a collection, here:

```
syntax match Enums "\<e_[A-Za-z]\+"
```

Comment: this answer came up in a review queue because of it's short length, care to explain your solution ?

Comment: Doesn't work, it will only highlight e_ this way.
I need to be able to highlight any words from the following: e_enum, e_foo, e_bar, e_randomword.

Comment: Sorry, I completely misunderstood your question.

Comment: Bloody hell, it's perfect. I think I tried something like
    syntax match Enums "\<e_\[A-za-z]\s\+"

Comment: @JonNimrod, consider upvoting and accepting the answer f it solves your issue.